# Why do date manipulation in Java with milliseconds?

Tags: java, date

I was recently faced with the problem of calculating the number of days from two dates in Java (without using joda, I'm afraid). Searching on the 'net shows most answers to this question say to get the milliseconds of the two days and convert that to days, which I found appalling. However, a scant few show a different approach: use a temporary variable to count how many times it takes adding 1 day to the first date to get to the second. This leaves the conversions to the code that does it best: the library.

Why do so many people advocate the first?

In another project, I had previously encountered numerous subtle date calculation problems involving time-zones, daylight-saving and once even leap years using seconds to do date comparisions and calculations. All these went away when *all* the comparison and calculation code was rewitten to use the language libraries. (This was in PHP, though, where the libraries are structured quite differently to Java.) So I'm understandably reluctant to use this "common wisdom" in the world of Java about comparing dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easy and efficient but definitely not something you want to put into production.

As an example, in the insurance industry, this mode of calculation can lead to an error of a day, at the correct boundary, could lead to an error of a year, leading to an incorrect age calculation and probably a rejection of an insurance claim :) (Look [here](http://tripoverit.blogspot.com/2007/07/java-calculate-difference-between-two.html) for a QED)

I did come across a disastrous situation where this millisecond manipulation was used in the UK (where they have DST) and it was a real mess to fix.

So to answer your question:

> Why do so many people advocate the first?

Because either they know the consequences and it doesn't apply to them or they are blissfully unaware and probably wont be around long enough to see the effects of this.

Comment: I agree completely. I don't know how many times I've run into problems because developers tend to do "simple" time arithmetics themselves, without having the slightest idea what they are all doing wrong.

Comment: that link is the *first* one I found that said **not** to use the milli-second methos. After I'd looked at half-a-dozen from Google... :-O

Answer (score 0):

Because it's easy and efficient.

Without referencing a single Javadoc page, I know all of the APIs that I need to manipulate Dates in the manner you describe: `java.util.Date#getTime()`, and basic arithmetic - *that's it*.

Yes, it's low-level, but Java's standard Date library is a disaster.

Comment: I originally said much the same thing. Problem is, I considered the Gregorian discontinuity and even leap seconds (the first completely doesn't matter and the second only matters to fairly specialized software), but missed the *rather more pressing* concern that some days have 23 hours, and some days have 25. (Daylight savings time issues.) That just kills it, basically. Thanks to @jambjo for pointing that out.

Comment: @T.J.: your point is completely valid. I think, however, that I interpreted the question differently. I read the question as asking why there are so many suggestions to do it this way. In no way is this approach better than Joda Time, _except for its extreme simplicity_. Also, it's **jarnbjo** (thanks, ligature!) :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest as much as possible your leave timezone conversions to front end GUIs. I suggest you have all your servers run in GMT (or some other fixed time) This will make your calculations much simpler as System.currentTimeMillis() is in GMT time. e.g. to get the day in GMT is just

```
long day = System.currentTimeMillis() / 86400000;
long anotherDay = anotherMillis / 86400000;
long intervalInDays = day - anotherDay;
```

As @Ryan states, you need to understand the consequences of using the date/time directly.

Using a higher level API can make your code much clearer, making it easier to maintain for others and less likely to make an error (now or in the future).

Using long is *much* faster, but for 90% of applications you don't need it and you are better off using a high level library. (Would still leave all servers with a consistent timezone and let the GUI decide how to display it)

You have to weigh up the cost of an error against the cost of potentially not being fast enough.